# Excel OR function does not behave as expected

Tags: excel

I have three columns A, B and C. If column A has a value greater than 150 or B has a value greater than 95, I want C to evaluate to TRUE, else FALSE. This is my attempt:

```
=OR(A2>150; B2>95)
```

The result of this is not as I expected. For example with A = 120 and B = 78, I get TRUE, which is clearly wrong. If I write `OR(120>150; 78>95)`, I get FALSE, as expected.

Is Excel reading A and B as strings? What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *text-that-looks-like-numbers*. You can convert them to numbers like this:

```
=OR(--A2>150,--B2>95)
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have formatted the cell as a number. How come it still behaves as text?

Comment: Changing the format to Number doesn't actually change it to a number. To do so - put `1` in a new cell, then copy the new cell. Then select A and B, and copy/pastespecial, using the *multiply* option.